# ISSN Calculator in Python

Tags: python, calculator

My task is to create an ISSN calculator, but I'm unsure what this means and how to do this. These are the instructions:

The procedure for calculating the check digit, which may be carried out automatically in a computer, is as follows:

1. Take the first seven digits of the ISSN (the check digit is the eighth and last digit): 0 3 1 7 8 4 7
2. Take the weighting factors associated with each digit: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
3. Multiply each digit in turn by its weighting factor: 0 21 6 35 32 12 14
4. Add these numbers together: 0+21+6+35+32+12+14 = 120
5. Divide this sum by the modulus 11: 120:11 = 10 remainder 10
6. Subtract the remainder from 11: 11-10 = 1
7. Add the remainder, which is the check digit, to the extreme right (low order) position of the base number of the ISSN: 0317-8471

If the remainder is 10, substitute an upper case X in the check digit position.
If there is no remainder, put a zero in the check digit position.

Here is my current code:

```
num = input("Enter a 7-digit ISSN number: ")
weight = 10 
total = 0 
arr = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] 
index = 0 
while index < 7: 
    print(arr[index])
    index += 1
    totalNum = int(num[index]) * arr[index]
print(totalNum) 
totalNum = totalNum % 11 
totalnum2 = totalNum - 11 
num = [num , totalnum2] 
print(num)
```

I get the output and error:

```
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 10, in <module>
    totalNum = int(num[index]) * arr[index]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: This is for ISSN calculator.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune sorry i am new to SO and am struggling with this program that I need to create. Where can I find an online tutor for Python right now?

Comment: I don't know where to find an on-line tutor.  On-line *tutorials*, however, are easy to find with a basic browser search of "Python tutorial".

Comment: As for down-voting the post, this is a natural part of the the process on Stack Overflow.  We expect that you complete the intro tour before you post, and take special note of the posting guidelines.  You'll find the rationale and ramifications in that tour.

Comment: Quite welcome.  Note that this question isn't closed yet.  Please consider going through the steps to make this a good SO question.  Code each of those steps in Python.  Do one step at a time, testing to make sure it works correctly before you go on.  If you get truly stuck at one step, you have your question: starting code, a failed attempt, and *one* thing to ask of SO.

Comment: Also, I suggest that you work around the input step.  Hard-code a number to work with: `digit_list = [0, 3, 1, 7, 8, 4, 7]` and then work through the arithmetic steps.  You can add the input part after you get the math working.  Use lots of `print` statements to trace your work.

Comment: @Prune Great thanks. I've worked on the code but I'm getting an error message.                                                                                              
num = input("Enter a 7-digit ISSN number: ")
weight = 10
total = 0
arr = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
index = 0
while index < 7:
    print(arr[index])
    index += 1
    totalNum = int(num[index]) * arr[index]
    print(totalNum)

totalNum = totalNum % 11
totalnum2 = totalNum - 11
num = [num , totalnum2]
print(num)

Comment: On line 7 in the code i pasted above (not sure how to format it in stack. it keeps going inline) anyway my error is that on line 7 it says the index is out of range, not sure what this means and how to fix it.

Comment: You have to edit the *question*; you can't format much in comments.  Again, that's in the intro tour.  :-)

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: @Prune hey I tried to but I cannot vote until I have a reputation of 15. You can archive this question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay; just accepting an answer will get the question archived.  You can do that much regardless of your reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMMEDIATE PROBLEM**

You increment your `index` value before you use it; this means that on the final iteration, it's 1 too large for the final operation.  Switch the bottom two lines of your loop:

```
index = 0 
while index < 7: 
    print(arr[index])
    totalNum = int(num[index]) * arr[index]
    index += 1
```

Even better, this should be a `for` loop, not a `while`:

```
for index in range(7):
    print(arr[index])
    totalNum = int(num[index]) * arr[index]
```

Python will guard your value better.

**AFTER THIS REPAIR:**

```
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
14
['0317847', -8]
```

Now, your problems include

- You keep only the last weighted amount in `totalNum`.  You need to make a running sum for the entire group.
- You have the final subtraction backwards.

I assume you can fix things from here.
Remember that you still have to handle the `X` case.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Note that you kept an open mind: a lot of people get upset that we don't write their homework for them, and simply leave.  Part of this community is getting you into the right communication methods.  Now that you see how, read the posting guidelines again: this gives you immediate feedback on the process.  BTW, I also have my bad days.

Comment: Would the person who down-voted please provide an explanation?  There's apparently something I could improve here.